# Python google search "advanced" argument unexpected

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-search

I'm trying to perform a google search using python, using the `googlesearch` python module. I don't just want urls to be outputted, I also want a description of the information in the url, basically web scraping.

Here's the code that includes the advanced argument:

```
from googlesearch import search

print(search('my search', advanced=True)) #advanced argument is true, to make the search detailed
```

but I get this error:

TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'advanced'

and I don't know why this is occurring.

I got this code from https://pypi.org/project/googlesearch-python. I would also like to note that I don't want to use other web scraping libraries, such as `bs4` (BeatifulSoup4) or `urllib`, especially since I want to figure out why the advanced argument isn't being accepted.

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace you get

Comment: How did you install it ? What version you have ?

Comment: @MarkusSafar, what do you mean by stacktrace? I installed it using pip, and I have version 3.0.0 currently.

Comment: Python version 3 ? Or google search version 3 ?

Comment: Google search version 3.

Comment: You install it using `pip install googlesearch-python`?

Comment: I installed it using pip install google

Comment: That a different package then the one you get code from

Comment: That worked, thank you. Now I'm having trouble actually accessing the results from the search, after running search('my search', advanced=True) it doesn't return anything. How do I get the results?

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](//developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](//policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, now I know that there is a google API for this. If this is true, then why would someone create the library in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing it using :

```
pip install googlesearch-python
```

Comment: That worked, but now when I run search('my search', advanced=True) it doesn't return anything. How do I get the results?

Comment: What you mean ?  It return none or what?

Comment: Like the program just finishes. Like you know when you write a function in a program, but you forget to actually run the function? Just like that, it doesn't return anything, it just ends the program.

Comment: Can you accept the answer and  create new question ? As it is a different issue not related to this one